# How move files based on file names in R?

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I know the question was asked many times but still i'm copying empty file. let's assume i have 50000k files and i have around 3000 file names as a vector so i want to move the files to different folder based on their names.

```
for (i in files) {
  for (j in files_names) {
    if ( i == j){
      
          file_copy(i, "C:/copy/to_this_folder")

    }
  }
}
```

But it moves the files but all of them were 0KB. Can any one please explain this to me

Comment: Please show how `files` and `file_names` are defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
letters
x = c("a", "b", "c", "2")
for (name in x[x %in% letters]) {
  file.copy(name, "tmp/")
}
```

Also, remember to use `getwd()` to check whether your working directory is correct or not.

Comment: wow...that worked...great thanks..Can you plase tell what did i wrong?..the path is right.

Comment: I'm glad to see that you can understand my code XD. I forgot to map that x is your "file" and letter is your "filenames".

I checked your code carefully, and I find the thing you want to copy is `j`, which is the iterator of the file names you would like to copy.

Comment: In my approach of mine, I use `x[x %in% letters]` to first find the "filename" in the "file" which will be copied, and this is also more "R-likely". Glad to answer your questions!